# Vue/Vuelidate: Dynamically show required star (*) based on requiredIf

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I'm creating a dynamic re-usable vue component that wraps a text input and includes the vuelidate validation stylings, etc.:

```html
<template>
  <div class="form-group" :class="{'form-group--error': validator.$error}">
    <label>{{ label }}<span v-if="validator.$params.required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text v-model="validator.$model" />
    <div class="error" v-if="validator.$error && !validator.required">* This field is required</div>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FormTextField",
  props: ["validator", "label"]
}
</script>
```

(validator prop is `$v` from parent)

The problem I have is trying to show the `<span>*</span>` dynamically based on if the field is required. This currently works (`v-if="validator.$params.required"`) as long as I only specify the `required` validator:

```js
fieldName: {
  required: required
}
```

Now, I need to instead declare my validation like this:

```js
fieldName: {
  required: requiredIf( ... )
}
```

The question is how to access the result of the `requiredIf` function? `validator.$params.required` will always be true since it's just checking if the param is there. And `validator.required` is the *status* of the validation, not the result of the requiredIf call to see whether it SHOULD be required or not.

Any suggestions on how I can show the required star dynamically based on vuelidate state?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `validator.$params.required`, check `validator.required`, which is only defined when there's a `required` or `requiredIf` validator rule applied. The value of `validator.required` is `true` when the field is missing, or `false` otherwise.

When the field is optional (has no `required`/`requiredIf` rule), the `validator.required` property does not exist, so we can't use `v-if="!validator.required"`. Instead, explicitly compare `validator.require` to `false`:

```html
<label>{{ label }}<span v-if="validator.required === false">*</span></label>
<div class="error" v-if="validator.$error && validator.required === false">* This field is required</div>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reading-requiredif-ec8bk?file=/src/components/FormTextField.vue)

Comment: the problem is the * disappears once the field is valid. I'm trying to have the * always there regardless of the validation status

Comment: I don't think it is possible. It would be good, if this worked:  'this.validations.$params?.requiredIf.prop()'. I chedked the validator and it doesn't return the prop() function.